# Can the predeterminer "half" comfortably occur before plural nouns without determiners?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, collocation, determiners, partitives

So "half" belongs to a special class of words known as "predeterminers", those that can occur before determiners:

> Half a century

> Half the people in this company can't speak a word of English

In English though, there are no indefinite (article-type) determiners in the plural: there are no plural equivalents to "a/an". This means that "half", as a predeterminer, does not have any determiner to "pre".

> Half Americans disapprove of the President (?)

> Half Japanese women prefer men who can cook (?)

Are these two last sentences incorrect in any way? Or could they sound awkward or unnatural? Should I use "half of" instead?

Comment: @nnnnnn That's a good point. Without a determiner in between, half could be mistaken for an adjective.

Comment: /'hæfə/ _Half a/Half of_ is the usual pronunciation. _Half a minute, OK? Half of Koreans make kimchi._  Determiners get crammed into a "determiner phrase" with its own limitations and contractions, mostly idiomatic. But don't call it a "determiner phrase" because that now means "noun phrase" to some linguists.

Comment: Isn't _some_ in _some men were standing by the lake_ an indefinite plural determiner?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Touche. Edited.

Comment: What do you consider a reputable source? An academic book or paper? A style guide or popular book on English usage such as Strunk and White? An example of the phrase being used in a professionally edited publication? Statistical evidence from corpora? Even if a source of some type can say if something is grammatical, the question of whether it is "comfortable", "awkward", or "unnatural" is often a matter of opinion or judgment, although perhaps somebody's opinion is good enough for you?

Comment: @StuartF  book by a well known language educator perhaps? A scientific paper backed by corpus data would be even better. I used the words "comfortable" and "natural" because even I was aware you can't always be prescriptive when it comes to language. If there's genuinely no "official" source, an answer by native speakers backed by other native speakers in the comment will have to do.

Comment: @StuartF There was this study on how Japanese verbs evolved that involved surveying multiple speakers on whether they treated certain irregular verbs as regular. I'd imagine something similar for this case would be optimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your question, I didn't quite understand what you're asking. Only after reading your own answer did I understand what you're asking and, more importantly, why you're asking what you're asking.

To quote your own answer:

> the contextual range for *half* is more restricted than *all* and *both*, both of which are also predeterminers. In short, unlike *all* and *both*, there **must** be a determiner after *half*.

So, you're comparing *half* with *all* and *both*, which is simply comparing apples with oranges. Firstly, *half* is a fraction, just as *quarter*, *third*, and *fifth* are.

Secondly, fractions can only function as predeterminers and cannot function as determiners, which means that they can come only before a determiner. So it's only natural that you can't say things like:

> **Half Americans disapprove of the President.*

Because you don't have any determiner right after the predeterminer!

In contrast, *both* and *all* can function as determiners as well as predeterminers. To quote the examples of your own answer:

> - half those oranges are rotten [predeterminer]
> - *both* the children came [predeterminer]
> - *all* the men went home and stayed there [predeterminer]
> - *all* lions are unpredictable [determiner]
> - *both* the dogs are friendly [predeterminer]
> - *both* dogs are friendly [determiner]
> - **half* people arrived [predeterminer]
> - **half* trains are always late in my country [predeterminer]

So you just have to know that *half* is a fraction whereas *all* and *both* are not, and therefore that *half* functions differently from *all* and *both*.

Comment: Now that you've put it like that, I realize @Tuffy 's comment above ("it must *literally* 'precede' a 'determiner'.") rings so true. None of the reputable British dictionaries I have access to lists *half* as a "determiner", unlike *all* and *both* which are both determiners and predeterminers. The so-called "zero determiner" applied to plural nouns are nothing but a lack of a visible, audible and literal determiners. It's interesting how there exists such asymmetry in English between singular nouns and plural nouns.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw Just like determiners, predeterminers are not a class of words, but simply a function of various classes of words. For example, even adjective phrase _that big_ can function as a predeterminer in _It's not that big a deal._ Here, the adjective phrase cannot come before _the deal_ or plural _deals_: *_It's not that big the deal._ *_They're not that big deals._

Answer (score 3):

I had to go to the third page of my search results but [ELT Concourse](https://www.eltconcourse.com/training/inservice/lexicogrammar/pre-_post-determiners.html) claims precisely that: the contextual range for *half* is more restricted than *all* and *both*, both of which are also predeterminers. In short, unlike *all* and *both*, there **must** be a determiner after *half*. Therefore, such phrase as "half Americans" is incorrect, and must be changed to "half of Americans", for example.

Here's an excerpt from the source:

> With plural count nouns we can use all three pre-determiners but *half* cannot be used with the zero article
>
> For example:
>
> - half those oranges are rotten
> - both the children came
> - all the men went home and stayed there
> - all lions are unpredictable
> - both (the) dogs are friendly
>
> but not with the zero article:
>
> - *half people arrived
> - *half trains are always late in my country

Comment: Could you please attribute the source, and paste the actual section that supports 'that' (ie answers 'Yes' to OP's title question)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sure thing, although I don't know how to format the blockquote to make it look nicer.

Comment: Also _half_ doesn't float like _all_ and _both_ (which is just suppletion for *_all two_). _All/Both (of) the boys left = The boys all/both left_, _Half (of) the boys left,_ but *_The boys half left_ (if it means anything, it doesn't mean half of the boys left).

Answer (score 1):

Just confirming a comment.

Both of the sentences are acceptable, but *mean* different things.

> Half of Japanese women prefer men who can cook.

This means that in a given population, we are speaking of 50% or so.

> Half Japanese women prefer men who can cook.

This would imply the women in question are half Japanese. See [a CNN article on Japan's hafu](https://www.cnn.com/2020/09/22/asia/japan-mixed-roots-hafu-dst-hnk-intl/index.html):

> The Japanese word "hafu" -- or "half" in English -- refers to people who are ethnically half Japanese, and is now used more for multiethnic people in general in Japan.

Comment: I am not at all sure that the concept of 'determiner' and 'predeterminer' is the most useful invention of that last grammatical century.  But, as I understand it, it must literally 'precede' a 'determiner'.  It is, however, odd that no other fraction happens to avoid the partitive preposition 'of'.

Comment: @Tuffy I believe that the overtones of the invention of the grammatical category are philosophical, and it's utility is the depths by which you want to plumb the ontological commitment of a phrase

Comment: I disagree. You have to hyphenate half-Japanese for anyone to take it that way. And although I would probably use “of” myself, I have no evidence that leaving it out is “wrong”. What authority do you have to support your statements?

Comment: @David Then take it up with author of the article whose work was rather comprehensible. I agree with your syntactical prescription, but language prescription is more an ought than an is.

Comment: My authoriy is present usage. I reject prescriptive grammar on the whole.

Comment: Let me explain. I am a scientist and on my “home” SE Biology site I would expect any answer to be supported with evidence or argument. That way the poster and others can determine objectively whether an answer is more than an opinion. The only way to judge here whether an unsupported opinion is correct is votes. However often in English people are convinced that the usage they are accustomed to, or the opinions of their schoolteachers, are correct, when in fact this is not the case. I’ve fallen into that trap frequently enough to be wary of my own authority — and that of others.

Comment: @David I respect that, but different disciplines have different methodologies,  and language is a normative and conventional enterprise. English has no authoritative body and even if it did,  it's doubtful it would have much value. There are schools of style.  Im a big believer in U of Chicago style, but there are several competing standards...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chicago_Manual_of_Style

Comment: A teacher could choose the AP or the MLA styles, but all of these choices are inherently precriptive. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription

Comment: A teacher choosing either one would do their pupils a disservice. Those sources are for paid professional writing. They consist of  collections of the time-honored shibboleths and crochets of old men with ink on their hands.  They have nothing to do with the English language, and they are useless in describing English syntax or grammaticality.

Comment: @JohnLawler lol Indeed. Well spoken. Some people just crave to be beholden to linguistic authority.